# Вопрос об использовании предлогов?

Tags: предлоги

Why do we say `пойти в спальню` and `пойти на кухню` why not `пойти в кухню`?

Comment: Questions like "why it is this way in the language and not another" in most cases have following answer: "just because".

Comment: Related: [Правило употребления предлогов “в” и “на”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/49590/190640)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "в кухне" and "на кухне"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22684/difference-between-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b5-and-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Comment: @Keselme If you say to someone: "Пошли в кухню...", it would be correct and natural. But this would be definitely taken in by your interlocutor as an overt allusion to go to the kitchen to have some "intercourse" or "to have a smoke" etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is some kind of archaism. Like in English language the difference between in school (inside the building) and at school (studying). I think historically "на кухню" was some kind of professional use of kitchen (the same way in Russian you can meet "он работает На радио, она - диктор НА телевидении"). Sometimes you should just remember: "**НА** хуторе", but "**В** деревне", but idiomatically "первый парень **НА** деревне" (it doesn't mean in village, it means among people in this village).

Answer (score 1):

There are also ways of using these prepositions in cant discourses. I.e. "пойти на хату" means "to go home", "войти в хату" means (in a thieves' cant) "to enter a cell", "прыгнуть в кухню" means "to enter a kitchen", "я на магазине" conveys the idea of my being "in a shop" as well as "by a shop". "У меня в кухне завелась мышь" = "У меня на кухне завелась мышь".

When there is the idea of application of professional activities the preference would be for "на кухне": Я работаю в ресторане на кухне (I work at the kitchen in a restaurant).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remember this form. Also: "на балкон", "на почту".